# Ordering by date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting a statement not ended properly when trying to do this query.  This is my first time really messing with dates.  I am trying to limit my results to only those things where the date field is from january 1st of 2013 and later.

```
select * from tab1
inner join tab2
on tab1.projectid = tab2.projectid
where tab1.client_id = 100
and tab1.sa_type_code = 'SUP'
and tab1.pl_category = 'CAT33'
where trunc(tab1.log_date) >= TO_DATE('01-jan-2013','dd-MON-yyyy');
```

thanks for the help

Comment: just use `and` instead of the last `where` It will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two `where` clauses:

```
select * from tab1
inner join tab2
on tab1.projectid = tab2.projectid
where tab1.client_id = 100
and tab1.sa_type_code = 'SUP'
and tab1.pl_category = 'CAT33'
and trunc(tab1.log_date) >= TO_DATE('01-jan-2013','dd-MON-yyyy');
```

If you actually want to order by the date, then add:

```
order by tab1.log_date
```

You might want:

```
order by tab1.log_date desc
```

to get the most recent dates first.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have two `WHERE clauses`, where the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) syntax allows only one clause.

```
select * 
from  tab1
inner join tab2
on    tab1.projectid = tab2.projectid
where tab1.client_id = 100
and   tab1.sa_type_code = 'SUP'
and   tab1.pl_category = 'CAT33'
and   trunc(tab1.log_date) >= TO_DATE('01-jan-2013','dd-MON-yyyy');
```